# Make a virtual WAN for software testing - Linux

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization

I am in the process of writing a socket program that will need to talk to different computers across the world. I want to set up a virtualized WAN on my computer so I can install the software on a virtual machine and test it's connectivity in a "real"ish WAN environment.

http://wanem.sourceforge.net/   Looks promising for setting up the WAN, but I was curious if anybody knew a better way to do it than setting up a bunch of virtual servers, and then another virtual server running WANEM to act as the WAN.  I have never been very successful with Virtual Nic's.

Comment: Not a great option - but if you have a few extra machines around, you can always physically set one up. I think we can all agree that's a gross option. I'd personally go with VMs, but yeah, I get that too can be weird for networking. +1 - interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what facet of the WAN you are trying to emulate. If you're using vmware then you can set up the hosts on a virtual LAN segment and then throttle the bandwidth and specify the packet loss over that LAN segment. wanem gives you the ability to control the latency as well.

Comment: Did not know that about VMWare I have been using virtual box, I will leave this open for a bit to see if anybody comes up with something really interesting, then make yours the answer